# RequireJs: Using optimizer plugin to optimize custom directory structure

Tags: jquery-mobile, requirejs, optimization

while creating a mobile web application using jquerymobile, jquery, requirejs, and backbone for routing, I was not able to optimize it by running the node.js command as instructed here:

http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

So basically, I was trying to optimize my files to run faster because it loads very slow in mobile devices and as the application goes larger and more complex so as it becomes more slowly.

An example structure of my application can be found here:

https://github.com/3na/PulawJS .

That is the skeleton of my application, I will be glad to hear any comments and suggestions from you guys.

Thank you so much!